# R Conditional summing

Tags: r

I've just started my adventure with programming in R. I need to create a program summing numbers divisible by 3 and 5 in the range of 1 to 1000, using the '%%' operator. I came up with an idea to create two matrices with the numbers from 1 to 1000 in one column and their remainders in the second one. However, I don't know how to sum the proper elements (kind of "sum if" function in Excel). I attach all I've done below. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
s1<-1:1000
in<-s1%%3
m1<-matrix(c(s1,in), 1000, 2, byrow=FALSE)

s2<-1:1000
in2<-s2%%5
m2<-matrix(c(s2,in2),1000,2,byrow=FALSE)
```

Comment: `in` is a reserved word in R, you won't be able to use it as a variable name

Comment: One way to sum conditionally is to `sum` a vector-product of a logical vector times the values. Another ways is with the `Filter` function and yet a third way is to select elements with "[" using a logical test.

Comment: what are your specific programming questions? please break down what you are struggling to understand about the problem you are facing and pose some questions so that others might help you better.

Comment: @RichardScriven Everyone's favorite error message: `Error: unexpected 'in' in "in"`

Comment: To find the values that are divisible by both you can simply use this: `s2[s2%%5 == 0 & s2%%3 == 0]`

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger: Great name and good work on the mind-reading as well. Fire Ecology sounds pretty exciting as a field of study. Out here in Calif we've given you a lot to study for the next decade or five.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger Or one can use simply `s2[s2 %% 15 == 0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, the best way is probably to find the least common multiple of the two numbers and check the remainder vs that:

```
# borrowed from Roland Rau
# http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Greatest-common-divisor-of-two-numbers-td823047.html
gcd <- function(a,b) if (b==0) a else gcd(b, a %% b)
lcm <- function(a,b) abs(a*b)/gcd(a,b)

s <- seq(1000)
s[ (s %% lcm(3,5)) == 0 ]
#  [1]  15  30  45  60  75  90 105 120 135 150 165 180 195 210
# [15] 225 240 255 270 285 300 315 330 345 360 375 390 405 420
# [29] 435 450 465 480 495 510 525 540 555 570 585 600 615 630
# [43] 645 660 675 690 705 720 735 750 765 780 795 810 825 840
# [57] 855 870 885 900 915 930 945 960 975 990
```

Since your `s` is every number from 1 to 1000, you could instead do

```
seq(lcm(3,5), 1000, by=lcm(3,5))
```

Just use `sum` on either result if that's what you want to do.

Props to @HoneyDippedBadger for figuring out what the OP was after.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
x =1:1000                  ## Store no. 1 to 1000 in variable x
x                          ## print x
Div = x[x%%3==0 & x%%5==0] ## Extract Nos. divisible by 3 & 5 both b/w 1 to 1000
Div                      ## Nos. Stored in DIv which are divisible by 3 & 5 both
length(Div) 
table(x%%3==0 & x%%5==0)   ## To see how many are TRUE for given condition
sum(Div)                 ## Sums up no.s divisible by both 3 and 5 b/w 1 to 1000
```

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks, will do. Learning in Process !! :)